# Uploading an Item with Metadata to an Amazon S3 Bucket using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I want to perform the same operation as below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-upload-bucket-item-with-metadata.html

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'  # v2: require 'aws-sdk'
      
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

file = 'C:\file.txt'
bucket = 'my-bucket'
      
# Get just the file name
name = File.basename(file)

# Create the object to upload
obj = s3.bucket(bucket).object(name)

# Metadata to add
metadata = {"answer" => "42"}

# Upload it      
obj.upload_file(file, metadata: metadata)
```

But getting error message in aws cli

```
C:\Users\upratik>aws s3 cp "C:\Amedments\sharepoint.docx" s3://pubmgmt-poc/ --metadata = '{"answer" => "42"}'
```

Unknown options: '{answer,=

Any help will be appricated on this.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you add `--metadata` to [aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) as follows:

```
--metadata="answer=42"
```

This will add [user-defined metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) to the object uploaded which  starts with `x-amz-meta`:

> When you upload objects using the REST API, the optional user-defined metadata names **must begin with "x-amz-meta-"** to distinguish them from other HTTP headers

For example:

[image]

I tested this on Linux, but don't see a reason why it would be different on Windows.

Comment: --metadata file_name="sharepoint.docx" is working fine for windows